# how to pass an string value in url in iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this **URL** I want to pass  `Self.Id`  in this url `cid=self.Id` .I am pass following why but getting result invalid request.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
    @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetCommentsForSMS?
     t=1&h=admin&last=0&cid=Self.Id&items=5"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestCompleted:)];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetCommentsForSMS?
     t=1&h=admin&last=0&cid=%@&items=5",Self.Id]];
```